# Are there standards/names to identify types of laptop keyboard/mouse layouts?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, mouse, keyboard-layout, standards

I feel like, prior to the release of the Apple MacBook Air in 2008, laptop keyboard/mouse layouts were quite different, with features such as:

- tactile buttons
- all keys at least as small as the letter keys
- separation of navigation keys
- function keys
- sunken mouse pad (away from fleshy base of the thumb)
- dedicated left/right mouse buttons

Whereas, after, every laptop manufacturer seemed to follow the MacBook Air's layout, with:

- linear chiclet buttons
- keys squashed/removed to fit an overall stylized shape
- navigation keys squashed into stylized shape
- media keys (with function keys a secondary purpose)
- mouse pad and palm rest at same level
- dual function mouse-pad/left-mouse-button (no right mouse button)

I'd really like to find a manufacturer who still creates the old-style layouts, but have no idea what those layouts might be called to search for them.

For example, when I'm looking for a desktop keyboard, I know to search for the standard "ISO 105 QUERY UK" to get the layout I'm looking for.

Do laptop layouts have standards/names?